# VHDL initial value is reset

Tags: vhdl

Declared initial value of signal is reset to 0 when a process is added (to my understanding that process shouldn't affect it).

Signal declaration:

```vhdl
signal current_level_index : integer range 0 to 7 := 6;
```

Process that causes the current_level_index initial value to be set to 0.

```vhdl
process (i_increase_level_clk) -- this clk is provided from a switch/button I have to physically press
    begin
-- deleting 3 lines below solves the problem
        if rising_edge(i_increase_level_clk) then
            current_level_index <= current_level_index + 1;
        end if;
end process;
```

Do you know what could be the reason for it?

I am not able to simulate this code, I compiled it with IceCube2 for the "Nandland Go Board (iCE40 HX1K VQ100 3.3V)" and observed the results on a display.

Here's the whole file:
https://github.com/michalmonday/files/blob/master/vhdl_issue/game_logic.vhd

Here's whole project:
https://github.com/michalmonday/files/tree/master/vhdl_issue

The same code/file has the same issue in another place:

```vhdl
    type level is record 
        pos : integer range -3 to 8;
        length : integer range 1 to 3;
    end record;

    type level_array is array (0 to 7) of level;

    signal levels : level_array := (
        -- pos, length
        (4,1),
        (4,1),
        (4,1),
        (4,2),
        (4,2),
        (3,3),
        (3,3),
        (3,3));
```

The "pos" of all levels is also set to 0 (it shouldn't be, it should be either 3 or 4). The "length" of all levels has always correct value.

Here's the part (process) of the code that affects position of levels:

```vhdl
    process (game_clk)      
        variable reverse_dir : std_logic := '0';
    begin
        if rising_edge(game_clk) then
            if levels(current_level_index).pos > 7 then
                reverse_dir := '1';
            elsif levels(current_level_index).pos < 1-levels(current_level_index).length then
                reverse_dir := '0';
            end if;

            if reverse_dir = '0' then
                levels(current_level_index).pos <= levels(current_level_index).pos + 1;
            else 
                levels(current_level_index).pos <= levels(current_level_index).pos - 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
```

Edit:
I think this may be the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23798653/4620679

Comment: Provide a [mcve] in your question, emphasis on minimal.

Comment: "I am not able to simulate this code" ... fix that.

Answer (score 1):

From "VHDL for Engineers" (p. 87, about ":=" operator) by Kenneth L. Short:

> "Initial signal values are useful for simulation, but not for
> synthesis. For synthesis, any initial or default value  assigned  to  a
> signal  is  ignored  by  an  IEEE  1076.6  compliant  synthesizer. This
> is  because  the  synthesizer  cannot  assume  that  the  target
> hardware  has  the capability to be powered up with its signals in the
> specified states. Note  that  there  are  some  synthesizers  that
> attempt  to  synthesize  initial  values (with varying degrees of
> success). However, for a design description to be IEEE Std1076.6
> compliant, initial values must not be assigned to signals or
> variables."

Comment: IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 RTL Synthesis the last revision has been withdrawn by the IEEE-SA. There are FPGA vendors who use the default values for objects that are targets of sequential logic (flip flops).  While there's talk of updating or inclusion in IEEE Std 1076, it's not controlling. You should rely on the target vendor or their synthesis tool for a determination of support.

Comment: iCE40 LP/HX Family Data Sheet, PLB Blocks, Logic Cells "Each Logic Cell includes three primary logic elements shown in Figure 2-2. ...• A ‘D’-style Flip-Flop (DFF), with an optional clock-enable and reset control input, builds sequential logic func- tions. Each DFF also connects to a global reset signal that is automatically asserted immediately following device configuration. ..." Which means the device on your NANDLAND board won't define initial values. It'd require more sophistication - programmable inversion to the FF (possible in LUT) *and* selective inverted FF output.

Comment: "Global Reset Control
The global reset control signal connects to all PLB and PIO flip-flops on the iCE40 device. The global reset signal is automatically asserted throughout the configuration process, forcing all flip-flops to their defined wake-up state. For PLB flip-flops, the wake-up state is always reset, regardless of the PLB flip-flop primitive used in the application."